# Reference auto in template parameter with std::enable_if_t in MSVC 2022

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, visual-studio-2022

I have a code that I can compiler without any issue with GCC 10. Unfortunately, this is not the case if I use Visual Studio 2022. The code is entirely based on templating (I do love those templates).

To optimize the selection of the correct classes, I use `std::enable_if_t` in the template declaration. The problem seems to come from the deduction of the referenced auto template member.

```
template<auto& _target,
         auto& _modifier,
         typename out_state, // Class for the outstate
         class actions = p::fsmm::will<fdefault<p::actions::nothing>>,
         std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<p::modifier, std::decay_t<decltype(_modifier)>>, void*> = nullptr >
class test {
};
```

The error this snippet generates is:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2065   '_modifier': undeclared identifier
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `auto&` NNTP seems evil.  Regardless, have you considered using concepts instead of SFINAE hacks?

Comment: Could you please make a [mre]? The namespace `p` isn't in the code. You can probably demonstrate the same issue without using that namespace anyway.

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://godbolt.org/z/fMEbv7hYP please work out what version of cl.exe you are using if you can.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/1qxxddsv5 is the concept version